# Google app engine endpoints for android suddenly not working when trying to launch in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an android project where I am using the generated client libraries for google app engine.  IT was working great until suddenly I am getting an error marker on the endpoint-libs folder.  inside the folder there is no specific file with an error market on it, but It wont let me launch the application.  I get no error in the console, and I did absolutely nothing to the code.  It simply just stopped working.  Does anyone know what might have caused this?  I appreciate any responses because i'm clueless.

Comment: in my opinion You may have to update your SDK to solve this problem. google api's being used maybe not up to date. just check.

Comment: Really doubt it, the old SDKs work fine.  But it's pretty hard to help you unless there's some indication of what the error is.  You can always try rebooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Eclipse shows the error indicator, but doesn't indicate which file has the error, look at Windows -> Show View -> Error Log or Problems (can't remember which of these it is).

(Often it is often a build or build path error in this case.)

Also, it is good to refresh and clean your project (project menu -> clean) in a situation like this

If those don't help, had you recently generated a new endpoints client library?  Or updated one of the SDK's?

Comment: Well, the problem I found in the Problems view like you said.  There was a tiny html error in the readme.html of the endpoint-libs folder that wouldnt let me compile my project.  It certainly made me laugh a bit.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have more success running my Android Cloud Endpoints application in the BlueStacks emulator versus the regular emulator. The regular emulator seems to be unsuccessful at running query operations frequently whereas Blue Stacks works quickly.